# Use MiniGrid environment with stable-baseline3

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I'm using MiniGrid library to work with different 2D navigation problems as experiments for my reinforcement learning problem. I'm also using stable-baselines3 library to train PPO models. but unfortunately, while training PPO using stable-baselines3 with MiniGrid environment, I got the following error.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kl9o.png)

I imported the environment as follows,

```
   import gymnasium as gym
   from minigrid.wrappers import RGBImgObsWrapper
   env = gym.make("MiniGrid-SimpleCrossingS9N1-v0", render_mode="human")
   env = RGBImgObsWrapper(env)
   env = ImgObsWrapper(env)
```

The training script using stable-baseline3 is as follows,

```
model = PPO('CnnPolicy', env, verbose=0)
model.learn(args.timesteps, callback)
```

I have done a quick debug and found a potential lead. I don't know if this is the real cause.
When I tried to load the environment directly from the gym the action space `<class 'gym.spaces.discrete.Discrete'>`. But when loaded from MiniGrid the action space is `<class 'gymnasium.spaces.discrete.Discrete'>`. Any help to sort out the problem is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That's the correct analysis, Stable Baselines3 doesn't support Gymnasium yet, so checks on `gym.spaces.discrete.Discrete` fail against `gymnasium`.

The following post answer explains how to workaround that, based on a currently open PR: [OpenAI Gymnasium, are there any libraries with algorithms supporting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75297606/openai-gymnasium-are-there-any-libraries-with-algorithms-supporting-it/75327755#75327755).